# How to configure windows for large number of concurrent connections

Tags: windows, networking, operating-system

I have seen many tutorial on how to tune Linux to scale  Node.js or Erlang server to 600K+ concurrent connections.

But I have not found similar tutorial for windows, can someone help with what are the similar knobs that exist for Windows.

/etc/security/limits.d/custom.conf

```
In root soft nofile 1000000
root hard nofile 1000000
 * soft nofile 1000000
 * hard nofile 1000000
 * List item
```

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
 fs.file-max = 1000000
 fs.nr_open = 1000000       
 net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 1048576
 net.nf_conntrack_max = 1048576
```

**“fs.file-max”**

The maximum file handles that can be allocated

**“fs.nr_open”**

Max amount of file handles that can be opened

**“net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max”**

how many connections the NAT can keep track of in the “tracking” table  Default is: 65536

Answer (score 0):

> // Increase total number of connection allowed
> [HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
> TcpnumConnections =  16,777,214
>
> // increase MaxFreeTcbs to > than number concurrent connection
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \System \CurrentControlSet \Services \Tcpip
> \Parameters] MaxFreeTcbs = 2000 (Default = RAM dependent, but usual
> Pro = 1000, Srv=2000)
>
> // Increase hash table size for the hashtable helping TCP lookup
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \System \CurrentControlSet \services \Tcpip
> \Parameters] MaxHashTableSize = 512 (Default = 512, Range = 64-65536)
>
> // reduce tcp delay to limit half-open connection
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System \CurrentControlSet \services \Tcpip \Parameters]
> TcpTimedWaitDelay = 120 (Default = 240 secs, Range = 30-300)